# Open a executable through filedialog this is getting errors - Why?

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone know why the following will Open the Kool.exe however the Kool.exe cannot load all of its files unless i place the current projects debug/project.exe into the same folder as the Kool.exe it is trying to open?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openF1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openF1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    openF1.Title = "Browse for Kool.exe...";
    openF1.CheckFileExists = true;
    openF1.CheckPathExists = true;
    openF1.DefaultExt = "exe";
    openF1.FileName = "Kool";
    openF1.Filter = "Kool (*.exe)|*.exe|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
    openF1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openF1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    openF1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
    openF1.ShowReadOnly = true;

    if (openF1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(openF1.FileName);
        if (pname.Length == 0)
        {
            Process.Start(openF1.FileName);
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Kool is already running.", "Patch: Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot find Kool install", "Patch: Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
}
```

Other: I am running the application as an administrator.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Setting the RestoreDirectory property to false would be a quick fix.

Comment: Might be a longshot, but if `kool.exe` is a local install and has stored its location in the registry, you could skip the filedialog and fetch the program location from the Windows registry instead, without giving the user a chance to start the wrong `kool.exe`.

Comment: Either use Hans' suggestion or use the ProcessStartInfo object and set its `[WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(openF1.FileName);]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I doubt that this has *anything* to do with the file open dialog.

I strongly suspect that the problem is that Kool.exe assumes that the files it needs are in the current working directory, instead of trying to find them relative to the executable file itself.

Ideally, you should fix Kool.exe to be more resilient - but if that's not possible, just set the new process's working directory when you start it.

```
string file = openF1.FileName;
string directory = new FileInfo(file).Directory;
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName = file,
    WorkingDirectory = directory
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

I am trying to open Kool.exe from filedialog, how would you set the new process's working directory based on openfiledialog?

Comment: @Burgo855: See my edit. It's important that you separate the "starting a process" from "choosing a file with OpenFileDialog". They're entirely separate tasks, and while you have problems with one you should isolate it from the other.